# Discovering tests and launching the MSTest runner is taking too long

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I am running some coded UI tests on parts of my UI. However, when I make a change and build the CUIT project, the discovering of the tests (all 6 of them) can take up to 10 minutes. Then following on from that, when I want to run the tests, they take another 10-15 minutes to even begin the test.

Because I am working in a team, with the same source, I asked a colleague to run the tests, and he can have them starting up within a minute. Now I have been stressing over this issue and looking everywhere for a solution.

A few things I have to point out:

- I have to use MSTest
- I have resharper installed but have disabled their unit test runner
- The discovery also struggles with my Unit test project
- I am running on an SSD

So my question is, does anybody know of any settings, or options that I may have to look in to speed things up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only a suggestion - you are running VS.net in administrator mode ? (even if you are an administrator yourself)

Comment: @PhillipH VS 2013 is running in administrator mode. That was one of my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I use something called TestDriven.Net to run all my MsTests. It has a couple of features which are simply too awesome to miss:

- You can assign keystrokes to go to test-code and back, which saves an obscene amount of clicking
- You can run or debug tests from assignable keystroke. What's better even is that you can re-run the previous tests that you ran also from a keystroke.
- (The best) TestDriven.Net disables all instrumentation that MsTest does, so it makes MsTest blazing fast - MUCH faster than nUnit for example.

I would definetly check it out. It may not look like much from the webpage, but the productivity boost and speed of this is simply insane:

http://testdriven.net/

The only thing that you MAY miss, is that it does all of it's output to the output window, and does not use the fancy forms in VS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a report of this here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2256847-starting-then-running-all-unit-tests-in-a-solution and their suggestion is to "For me, the issue was resolved by unchecking the testsettings file under Test => Test Settings in the main menu of Visual Studio (2015)."

I can't say I've had this problem or tried this fix - but give it a go, it might just work.

Comment: Unfortunately we need the test settings files for our test runs, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the architecture to X64 and it seems to work great!
Test => Test Settings => Default Processor Architecture => X64